# Can I use a lay back post on a Schwinn Meridian 26" tricycle?

Tags: saddle, tall, schwinn

I just purchased a 26" Schwinn Meridian trike.  I am 6'3" and am wondering if I can use a set back or lay back seat post in order to get a little more leg extension.  Are there any suggestions about the appropriate seat post to use?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  If you need more leg length, then normally you would just want a higher saddle, unless there's something different about the geometry.  Pictures would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setback or lay back seat post.

You'll need to find one with the right size post diameter. The best way to find the right size is to measure the one you have. Sizes range from 25.0 and up measured in tenths of a millimeter. A typical size might be 26.4mm. Measure your post with digital calipers or let a bike shop measure it.

Keep in mind that using a setback seat post will not only give you more leg room it will also shift your weight backwards and increase the distance to the handlebars.

It's always important to make sure that the seat post is inserted past the minimum insertion point. If you need the post higher than the minimum insertion point then you need a new post.

It's hard to recommend any one type. The first thing is to find one that fits and then evaluate how much setback you need. It will come down to personal preference.
It would be nice if you could try a few different styles to find what works.

Comment: Thanks....I have it at a bike shop for assembly right now and will ask the mechanic there to see what I might use.